# If greater than divide by value elif pass

Tags: python, python-3.x, divide

I want to change all the values of the column `FuelFlow` in `df_OmanAirTO` that are larger than `5800`. The values larger than `5800` should be divided by `2,2046226218`. The other values that are smaller than `5800` should stay the same.

I am a beginner in Python and tried the following:

```
for row in df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow:
    if row>=5800:
        df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow/2.2046226218
    elif row<=5800:
        pass
    print(df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow)
```

I am not receiving an error, but my values in the column `FuelFlow` have not changed either. What would be a right script?

Thank you for helping me in advance!

Comment: `df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow = df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow / 2.2046226218` and you don't actually need the `elif` part since you don't do anything there.

Comment: even better `df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow /= 2.2046226218`, but that will change the list values. A [mcve] is required: must be a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : though `/=` is more concise, I am not sure this is actually better : the more verbose version is also more explicit.

Comment: in-place is usually faster because it doesn't re-create an object to destroy the old one.

Comment: @Faibbus Above solution would change the value of the whole column and now only that specifics which are greater than 5800.

Comment: @Faibbus you've been sucked into OP next problems.  A [mcve] is required in those cases, to avoid debugging the rest of OP code. Don't answer unclear/typo questions like that. vote/flag to close instead

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow / 2.2046226218
```

You just compute the division, and throw away the result.

In order to update the column, you'd have to write:

```
for row in df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow:
    if row>=5800:
        df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow = df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow / 2.2046226218
        # or, using shorthand as suggested by Jean-François Fabre
        # df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow /= 2.2046226218
    print(df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow)
```

Comment: df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow = df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow / 2.2046226218 : Will it not update all column values and not only values which are grater or equal to 5800. and also with each iteration, if we divide, the value will become less as it will perform operation on the whole column?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I changed it into the following:
for row in df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow:
    if row>=5800:
        df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow /= 2.2046226218
print(df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow)

This results in all values becoming zero. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue: I have defined a separate method to check condition and perform operation.

```
# Method to check condition
def div(value):
    if value >= 5800:
        value /= 2.2046226218
    return value

# To perform operation row wise in an efficient way.
df_OmanAirTO.FuelFlow = df_OmanAirTO.loc[:,'FuelFlow'].apply(lambda row: div(row))
```

In case, if you have any doubt, you can ask.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping. When I do this, it changes all values into None. Do you know why?

Comment: @L.Nieuwendijk : You do not have to perform the loop you have defined and have you replaced your part of code with this one. Make sure that indentation is correctly done. Also, make sure that the value in FuelFlow is in 'int' or if it is in string: change 5800 to '5800' else you can provide a sample dataframe on which this part could be tested.